# How do you specify the origin of the arrow on a popover segue with OS X 10.10 storyboards

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsviewcontroller, nspopover

I'm playing around with storyboarding in an OS X 10.10 app.  I have an `NSTableView` that, when you click a specific row opens a segue that goes to a popover that contains an `NSViewController`.

How do you specify the origin `NSPoint` of the arrow for the popover?  Right now, it just points to the `NSTableView` in the middle.  I assumed that I could do this in `prepareForSegue`, but I can't seem to figure it out.  `prepareForSegue` doesn't seem to have an understanding that the `NSViewController` is contained in an `NSPopover`

Any ideas?

Comment: You should ask that kind of question at Apple's forums.

Comment: With respect, have you ever used Apple's dev forums?

Comment: Yes.  I've been using it since February, 2011.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to file a radar and/or post on Apple forums.

Answer (score 5):

You should file an enhancement request Radar for this behavior if you think it should be provided by the framework in some way.

---

But to workaround this in the meantime, you can create your own custom NSStoryboardSegue subclass to help with this.

```
@interface TablePopoverSegue : NSStoryboardSegue

@property (weak) NSTableView *anchorTableView;
@property NSRectEdge preferredEdge;
@property NSPopoverBehavior popoverBehavior;

@end

@implementation TablePopoverSegue

- (void)perform {
    if ([self anchorTableView]) {
        NSInteger selectedColumn = [[self anchorTableView] selectedColumn];
        NSInteger selectedRow = [[self anchorTableView] selectedRow];

        // If we can pick a specific row to show from, do that; otherwise just fallback to showing from the tableView
        NSView *anchorView = [self anchorTableView];
        if (selectedRow >= 0) {
            anchorView = [[self anchorTableView] viewAtColumn:selectedColumn row:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
        }

        // Use the presentation API so that the popover can be dismissed using -dismissController:.
        [[self sourceController] presentViewController:[self destinationController] asPopoverRelativeToRect:[anchorView bounds] ofView:anchorView preferredEdge:[self preferredEdge] behavior:[self popoverBehavior]];
    }
}

@end
```

This can be specified in IB in the inspector panel for the segue (just like iOS):

[image: Segue Inspector Panel in IB]

And then in your source view controller's prepareForSegue:, you can just set up the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[TablePopoverSegue class]]) {
        TablePopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (TablePopoverSegue *)segue;
        popoverSegue.preferredEdge = NSMaxXEdge;
        popoverSegue.popoverBehavior = NSPopoverBehaviorTransient;
        popoverSegue.anchorTableView = [self tableView];
    }
}
```